# OnePlus 3: Disable hotspot turning off automatically

Tags: wifi-tethering, 7.0-nougat, oneplus-3, oxygenos

After updating OnePlus 3 to OxygenOS 4.0.1 the option to keep hotspot on even no devices are connected seems to be missing. I need to keep hotspot on all the time and only manually to shut it down. How to enable this feature?

Comment: Use Bluetooth sharing (just above hotspots on ...more settings page.

Comment: @MichaelPearson So you say BlueTooth tethering won't disconnect?

Comment: https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/tethering-disconnects-after-5-minutes-whether-in-use-or-not.486950/

Comment: I'm trying USB tethering now

Comment: So far USB tethering seems to work. That can be one workaround then.

Answer (score 2):

Nougat update for OnePlus 3 and 3t is extremely fresh (I managed to upgrade it only using a VPN to Canada). This must be one of the features which still needs to be polished. The checkbox is missing to keep the hotspot running even if noone is connected for more than 5 minutes.

Until OnePlus releases a new minor update to fix this, workaround can be either using USB tethering or Bluetooth tethering (reported by @MichaelPearson).

---

Got another update (01/17) over the air towards the end of January, that still doesn't have the checkbox.

---

The latest update (as of 2017 November) still doesn't have it

Answer (score 2):

Workaround when you are (like me) dependent on the Wifi hotspot: Create a script with [Automate](http://llamalab.com/automate/) which automatically reactivates the hotspot:

[image: Automate script for reactivating Wifi hotspot]